# Pass property to component

Tags: javascript, react-native, native-base

I have simple footerTab where I would like to show badge if there is notifications.

```
<Button active={ this.props.ui.selectedTab === 'notifications' ? true : false } 
        onPress={ () => this.selectedTab('notifications') }
        { ...this.props.ui.notifications ? badge : null }    
>
        { this.props.ui.notifications ? 
          <Badge><Text style={{ color:'white' }}>{this.props.ui.notifications}</Text></Badge> : null
        }
        <Icon name='md-notifications' />
</Button>
```

With this code I'm getting 'badge is not defined'

How I can pass that badge property for Button ?

Comment: Where is `badge` defined?

Comment: Hmm. Good question. I haven't defined it anywhere because I have thought that is just property for component <Button badge></Button>. Should I pass that property as string to component ?

Comment: Are you using a library for Badge component? Or did you create a Badge component yourself?

Comment: Button, Footer and badge property for Button, all are from native-base library.

Comment: Is badge a prop of Button? If so you probably want to change that to `badge={!!this.props.ui.notifications.length}`, I'm assuming you want this badge to show if there are notifications. If there is no badge property for Button then this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

After a while I realised that property badge was boolean with default true. So working version was like this.

```
    <Button active={ this.props.ui.selectedTab === 'notifications' ? true : false } 
        onPress={ () => this.selectedTab('notifications') }
        badge={ this.props.ui.notifications ? true : false }    
    >
        { this.props.ui.notifications ? 
          <Badge><Text style={{ color:'white' }}>
       {this.props.ui.notifications}</Text></Badge> : null
        }
        <Icon name='md-notifications' />
    </Button>
```